# Dealing with errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, discord.js

I want the bot to receive a `/dm` command and then send a DM to a specific person. Target is `targetid` and the DM content is `letter`. The command itself works - it's the error catching that doesn't work. If I make `targetid` something like `267` or any other impossible `targetid`, it won't output the error as a new message.

```js
try {
    client.users.fetch(targetid).then((user) => {user.send(letter);})
    message.react("✅")
} catch (err) {
    message.channel.send("❗ Something went wrong! Refer to the error log below.\n\n ``" + err + "``\n(Bot administrator contacted: <@...>)") //Removed my ID
    message.react("❌")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Promise#catch()` instead of normal try/catch, since that's what `fetch()` returns:

```js
client.users
    .fetch(targetid)
    .then(user => {
        user.send(letter)
        message.react('✅')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        message.channel.send('❗ Something went wrong! Refer to the error log below.\n\n ``' + err + '``\n(Bot administrator contacted: <@...>)') //Removed my ID
        message.react('❌')
    })
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)